# Exportar los nuevos cambios a producción en la base de datos MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

actualmente tengo el siguiente problema, pasa que en local voy generando tablas y propiedades, y cuando ya tengo algo nuevo integrado tengo que estar revisando las tablas de producción y agregar las nuevas tablas, saben si existe alguna aplicación donde compare la tabla de producción con la de desarrollo y así que haga los cambios automáticamente sin tenerlo que hacer todo manual, o debe haber una forma de facilitar este proceso.

Saludos.

Comment: Dejame ver si entendi, tienes la "Tabla 1" con numeros del 1 al 10, despues tienes la "Tabla 2" con los mismos datos, al agregar algo mas a la "Tabla 1" quieres actualizar automaticamente la "Tabla 2"?

Comment: No te sirve [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx)?

Comment: Si imaginate, que tienes una base de datos local, donde tiene una tabla llamada clientes, y tienes la misma tabla en producción. pero resulta que conforme va avanzado el desarrollo, pues agregas nuevas tablas, nuevas propiedades y esto se vuelve tedioso cuando todos estos cambios necesitas ponerlo en producción, en el código no hay problema lo suaves y ya pero en la base de datos ahí es donde tengo el problema.

Answer (score 1):

lo mejor respecto a este tipo de temas es consultarlo con el DBA de tu organización, generalmente hay procedimientos para este tipo de tareas.

Si no cuentas con este contexto de trabajo y tienes que hacerlo tu solo, te recomiendo que verifiques esta herramienta  [Red Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) , tiene una interfaz visual para comparar las bases y generar los scripts de cambio automaticamente, tienes 14 dias de prueba y si te resulta útil, puedes proponer a tu organización que compre la licencia.

Hay otras altenativas gratuitas de herramientas similares como esta [dbForge Schema compare](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/) , pero no la use tanto como la primera que me resulto muy práctica y sencilla de usar.

Saludos

Fernando

Comment: Por otra parte, los muchachos de Redmond te facilitan de forma gratuita [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt204009.aspx) como herramienta dentro de Visual Studio (cualquiera de sus ediciones).

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, que tiene una herramienta que permite realizar comparaciones entre dos esquemas de bases de datos, tanto a nivel de datos como de diseño.

1. Crear un proyecto de tipo "database"
   [image: crear proyecto]
2. En el menú View, seleccionar Server Explorer y crear las dos conexiones que necesitas: una de desarrollo y otra de Producción
3. Vas al menú Tools - SQL Server - New schema comparison
4. Das click en la pestaña que dice Select Source y eliges la conexión de desarrollo; luego en select target eliges la de producción.
5. Haces click en el botón compare y esperas que termines. Luego en esa misma barra tienes la opción de actualizar el target (producción) o simplemente visualizar dónde están las diferencias.

**Nota: Realiza un backup o Script de tu base de datos de producción antes de actualizar.**

Necesitas un usuario con permiso para crear objetos en el target.